# Provider does not support changing store on the fly with TabViewAnimated

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am getting the following error when attempting to switch to another tab via TabViewAnimated in my React Native app.

[image]

I have two sub-components and Provider is used as follows:

```
 render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <TabViewAnimated
                    style={styles.container}
                    navigationState={this.state}
                    renderScene={this._renderScene}
                    renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
                    onRequestChangeTab={this._handleChangeTab}
                />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
```

The first sub-component has access to the state tree via props, but when loading the second sub-component I get the error.

My dependencies are as follows:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "^0.44.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "0.0.66",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time `render` is called a new `store` instance is created, which causes this error.

You can solve this by instantiating your store in a place where it will happen only once, usually at the entry point of your application or in a separate file that exports it:

```
// store.js
export default createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
```

and

```
// App.js
import { store } from './store'

...

  render() {
    <Provider store={ store }> ... </Provider>
  }
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Update: created the store using my old method, but in the parent class of the component hierarchy, and the issue is no more. Your diagnosis was correct, the issue was that every time the tab changes, the render method is called again, thus creating a new store. Thanks!